# How to add an image as a header/footer in Markdown for a PDF document

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I want to add images as headers and footers (in keeping with my organizations visual identity) to PDF reports. I've managed to do it in Sweave but I'd also like to be able to do it using just Markdown.  I can  insert the image using `![footer](H:/R/Footer.pdf)` however when I try to use the wallpaper package (like I do in Sweave) I get an error.

```
---
title: "2014 Report"
author: "My Name"
date: "Monday, October 06, 2014"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
fontsize: 10pt
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{wallpaper}
abstract: This is my abstract
---
\LRCornerWallPaper{0.99}{![footer](H:/R/Footer.pdf)}
```

Is there a way in Markdown, or do I need to stick to Sweave?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would imagine the contents of `\LRCornerWallPaper{}` need to be in LaTeX format (includegraphics), since (presumably) pandoc wouldn't try to interpret it.

Comment: That is the LaTeX format using the wallpaper package. I just include it right after \begin{document}.

Comment: Can you add a minimal pure LaTeX working example? It seems to work alright with `\LRCornerWallPaper{0.99}{path\to\pic}`, but does not with `![footer]` option. And I didn't find this usage in the documentation.

Comment: Ahh, ok. That works - can you add it as an answer? I was combining Markdown language with Latex language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct usage of the `wallpaper` package in this case would be simply

```
\LRCornerWallPaper{0.99}{path/to/pic}
```