# How to add an image as a footer in Markdown for a ioslides_presentation

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Hi I  want to add images as footers to `ioslides_presentation` with `shiny widgets`. I tried to reproduce this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238722/how-to-add-an-image-as-a-header-footer-in-markdown-for-a-pdf-document) but it didn't work. I want to add this .png file as a footer:

[image]

```
---
title: ""
author: ""
date: ""
output: 
  ioslides_presentation
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{wallpaper}
runtime: shiny
---
\LRCornerWallPaper{0.99}{footer.png}
```

Comment: That example uses latex. ioslides is HTML. I'd suggest researching the CSS styles used and then insert something via CSS, targeting `slides > slide`

Comment: @hrbrmstr I found sth like this https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/435 but when I implement it into default css it still doesn't work.