# Pictures as headers in R-markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I want to add an image as a header on the upper right corner of every page of my word document, using r-markdown with R-Studio.
I found a solution accepted by community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238722/how-to-add-an-image-as-a-header-footer-in-markdown-for-a-pdf-document), but there is only the proper command in Latex described, there is no working example. For me the offered solution did not work.

Therefore I provide my sample code:

```
---
title: "2014 Report"
author: "My Name"
date: "Monday, October 06, 2014"
output:
  word_document:

fontsize: 10pt
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{wallpaper}
abstract: This is my abstract
---

Test

\ThisURCornerWallPaper{0.1}{header.png}

Here is some text.
```

That code produced the following output:
[image: Output]

As one can see, there is no picture included in the document. Can somebody provide me with an actually working example (other ideas that do the job are also welcome)?

Comment: I dont have word but it might be possible by changing the word template. Here is a related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29442742/1777111

Comment: This also might help (I tried it earlier with a similar but slightly different problem and got good results): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021880/rmarkdown-to-word-output-insert-image-above-header